# Appending rows for Pandas Dataframe whilst conserving types

Tags: python, pandas, types, boolean

I have a pandas dataframe to which I want to incrementally append rows. My issue is that when trying to happen values, their type is lost. This is especially annoying for `'boolean'` which become `'object'` (`int` becoming `float` is still a bad thing but at least the rest of the program can still run, just less efficiently):

```
data1 = pd.DataFrame()
data1['foo'] = 5
print("*\n",data1.dtypes)
data2 =pd.DataFrame()
data2['bar'] = True
print("**\n",data2.dtypes)
data3 = pd.concat([data1, data2])
print("***\n",data3.dtypes)
data4 = data1.append(data2)
print("****\n",data4.dtypes)

*
 foo    int64
dtype: object
**
 bar    bool
dtype: object
***
 bar     object
foo    float64
dtype: object
****
 bar     object   # <-- bool type becomes object
foo    float64
dtype: object
```

Do you have an idea how to prevent it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution to the issue :

The type of columns is changed to allow the representation of the missing values which are represented by `np.nan` (either because the row adds or misses some columns compared to the dataframe it get append to) .

Empirically, appending/concatenating a new row inducing missing information will change the types in this manners:

- `int64` -->`float64`
- `bool` --> `float64` if using a dictionary to set the new line
- `bool` --> `object` if using a dataframe to set the new line

Comment: Do you have a reference to this in the docs, or did you just figure it out by trying different things?

Comment: This was obtained [Empirically](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/empirically)

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
# https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html
# create DataFrame
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df.dtypes
col1    int64
col2    int64
dtype: object

# Keep dtypes
ser_types = df.dtypes

ser_types
col1    int64
col2    int64
dtype: object

# Chnange dtypes for test purpose
df = df.astype('float64').copy()

df.dtypes
col1    float64
col2    float64
dtype: object

# Series dtype to dictionary
ser_types.to_dict()
{'col1': dtype('int64'), 'col2': dtype('int64')}

# Chnage dtype from initial df
df = df.astype(ser_types.to_dict()).copy()

df.dtypes
col1    int64
col2    int64
dtype: object

df
col1    col2
0   1   3
1   2   4
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question mixes between rows and columns.
In pandas, each column has a type, and each row get the types of each of its columns.

When you do `data1['foo'] = [some values]` you define a new **column**
and when you append two dataframes with different names of columns, then you:

> Append rows of other to the end of this frame, returning a new object.
>   **Columns not in this frame are added as new columns.**

(see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html))

On the other hand using `concat` do column stack of dataframes, keeping the column data type.

Last, note that your column assignment need to use brackets. i.e.

```
data1['foo'] = [5]
```

instead of

```
data1['foo'] = 5
```

**EDIT:** in the spirit of your comment I did a small experiment trying to follow your intention:

```
df = pd.DataFrame() # Creating a DF
df['a'] = [1,2,3] # Adding a column of integers
df['b'] = [True, False, True] # Adding a column of Boolean
print df['b'].dtype

>bool
```

We see that indeed col 'b' is bool.

Adding a row with partial data:

```
df = df.append({'a':1}, ignore_index=True)
print df['b'].dtype

>float64
```

Now col 'b' changed to float64, to support the NaN type. That's the known numpy NaN [gotcha](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#nan-integer-na-values-and-na-type-promotions).

Last, printing the `df` results with:

```
print df

     a    b
0  1.0  1.0
1  2.0  0.0
2  3.0  1.0
3  1.0  NaN
```

Comment: I don't think there is a mix between columns and rows here. The goal is to append a new rows containing possibly different sets of columns. When the column does not exist in one of the dataframe, I'd like it to beconserve its type after the appending/concatenation since technically its contains is untouched (exept for the missing values). My guess was that empty values are by default `np.nan` (correct me) which does not exist for `int64 `or `bool` and thus the columns get its type switched to store simultaneously the existing data and the `np.nan`

Comment: Now I understand you better but not completely. Could you update your question with pseudo-code in comments? I.e. on each step explain exactly what you intend to do, and what do you expect to happen.

Comment: Following your comment, I edited my answer with additional information.