# How to return True/False instead of 1/0 in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to evaluate two floating point values in a loop and for some reason the evaluation returns 1/0 instead of True/False.

```
def new_row(item1, item2):
    new_row = {
    'lister': item1,
    'metric': item2
    }
    return new_row

final_df = pd.DataFrame()
lister = ['a', 'b', 'c']
position = [1.1, 2.3, 4.5]
evaluation_metric = [0, 0.5, 0.2]
    for b1 in lister:
        print(abs(position) > evaluation_metric)
        metric = (abs(position) > evaluation_metric)
        nr = new_row(lister, metric)
        final_df = final_df.append(nr, ignore_index=True)
```

For some reason when I print I get True but when I append it to the final `df` I get 1.0. Any thoughts on how to get True in the `final_df` instead of 1.0?

Comment: i think i understand what you are trying to do, but `(abs(position) > evaluation_metric)` is going to throw an error because you cannot apply this function to a `list`

Comment: we can't read in code, we can't read in your mind - you have to put all details in question (but not in comments)

Comment: Please making this a runnable script so we can test with it.

Comment: I don't understand which line makes problem - where do you have `1/0` maybe you have column defined as float values and it automatically convert boolean to float

Comment: @furas - I think it would be best if poster made a working script before adding more words. If I understand it, `metric` is boolean but the dataframe ends up as an integer after the append. If we had working code, ti would be more clear.

Comment: @tdelaney I agree with you

Comment: @furas I think you should write it as `1`/`0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created a dataframe without columns so pandas had to guess what to do when a row was appended. In a similar experiment, it chose `float64`:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame()
>>> final = df.append({"lister":"a", "metric":False}, ignore_index=True)
>>> final
  lister  metric
0      a     0.0
>>> final.dtypes
lister     object
metric    float64
dtype: object
```

You could fix the dtype after you've done the appends

```
>>> final["metric"] = final["metric"].astype(bool)
>>> final
  lister  metric
0      a   False
```

But you likely shouldn't be appending in the first place. `pandas` lets you perform operations on entire columns. Create columns from your lists first, then do the operation in a single step, as in

```
import pandas as pd

lister = ['a', 'b', 'c']
position = [1.1, 2.3, 4.5]
evaluation_metric = [0, 0.5, 0.2]

df = pd.DataFrame({"lister":lister, "position":position, 
    "evaluation_metric":evaluation_metric})

df["metric"] = df["position"] > df["evaluation_metric"]

print(df)
```

Output

```
  lister  position  evaluation_metric  metric
0      a       1.1                0.0    True
1      b       2.3                0.5    True
2      c       4.5                0.2    True
```

If you don't need those other columns any more, you can drop them

```
df.drop(["position", "evaluation_metric"], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the code that you posted won't run (and it would be advised you fix this so your question isn't closed), the issue is that appending rows with type `bool` to an empty DataFrame will lead to conversion to `float64` (according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41023525/appending-rows-for-pandas-dataframe-whilst-conserving-types)):

For example:

```
for l,p,e in zip(lister,position,evaluation_metric):
    metric = (abs(p) > e)
    nr = new_row(l, metric)
    final_df = final_df.append(nr, ignore_index=True)

>>> final_df.dtypes
lister     object
metric    float64
```

You can fix this by modifying your `new_row` function to return a DataFrame, then concatenating this your to final_df in each loop iteration:

```
def new_row(item1, item2):
    new_row = {
    'lister': [item1],
    'metric': [item2]
    }
    return pd.DataFrame(new_row)

final_df = pd.DataFrame()
lister = ['a', 'b', 'c']
position = [1.1, 2.3, 4.5]
evaluation_metric = [0, 0.5, 0.2]

for l,p,e in zip(lister,position,evaluation_metric):
    metric = (abs(p) > e)
    nr = new_row(l, metric)
    final_df = pd.concat([final_df,nr])
```

Output:

```
>>> final_df
  lister  metric
0      a    True
0      b    True
0      c    True
```